# "Retrieve" vs "Recover"

Tags: difference, word-difference

Do these words have a similar meaning in this context?

- You need to recover/retrieve his sword from the cave.
- You need to recover/retrieve his body from the grave.

Comment: From [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Gwen_Araujo), *Alameda County Sheriff's Office dispatched ... two detectives **to recover the body from the grave** site.* Looks perfectly natural to me. And Google Books has hundreds of instances of [*recover the sword from*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22recover+the+sword+from%22), many of which I'm sure would be sufficiently similar to OP's example that they justify using it there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other key difference that is sometimes applicable to **retrieve** vs **recover** is that the former tends to imply that you already know and have known where the thing is while the latter implies that the thing was lost, but then you found it again.

Depending on context, that distinction might not work so well with the body in the grave example because it's hard to lose a body in a space so small as a grave – unless you're trying to say that the grave itself was lost, i.e., you didn't know where the person was buried until just recently – so Tᴚoɯɐuo gives a good explanation of other nuances of meaning at play in that case.

But in the case of the sword in the cave, they have different implications.

"Retrieve the sword from the cave" makes it sound like getting the sword is a simple task of walking in, picking up the sword, and walking out, like you're just running an errand for someone.

"Recover the sword from the cave" implies that the sword has been missing for a long time, but now you got some info that it's in the cave, so you're going to go get it. Or it could be that the sword is *figuratively* lost to you, even though you've actually known that it's in the cave the whole time. Maybe that's because the sword being guarded by a ferocious dragon, or maybe you just dropped it off a cliff and you're gonna need some climbing equipment to go down and get it – whatever the case, it won't be so simple as just walking in and picking it up.

Comment: So **recover** makes getting something harder in a certain way?

Comment: @SovereignSun Yes, I would say so.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of **retrieve** as meaning "to fetch and bring back", whereas **recover** means "to bring back to a fitting place or state".

To **retrieve** human remains casts them as an object, like a package. There's no dignity to the phrase, whereas to **recover** mortal remains preserves human dignity.

Comment: But you can retrieve people such as [soldiers](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22retrieved+soilders%22): "_The Medical Air Evacuation units retrieved soldiers from Normandy._" "_natives who ... retrieved soldiers from jungle labyrinths and choppy seas._" or just [retrieve a random "I"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+was+retrieved%22).